# Socket.IO couldn't connect on mobile

Tags: mobile, websocket, socket.io

I implemented websocket transport with latest (1.3.5) Socket.IO, using node.js as a backend.

Handshake and data exchange works well in the latest desktop browsers. But Safari on 8.1.2 iOS and 38 Chrome on Android couldn't connect to server over WiFi. Do anybody faced the same problem or know what's wrong here?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These screenshots show that you're trying to connect to `localhost`.  If you're on a mobile device, `localhost` is the mobile device itself, not your node.js server. You will need to use the IP address or DNS name of your server, connect to that instead and you will need to make sure your WiFi network has access to the node.js server.